# Python create list of function pointers to be called later specifying arguments at creation

Tags: python

The easiest way to explain the problem is by showing the code:

```py
def foo(stuff):
    print(stuff)

fun_list = [lambda :foo(i) for i in range(5)]

for fun in fun_list:
    fun()
```

When the functions are called they all print `4`. I would like them to print the actual value of `i` from when they were created, so `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. This is all part of a large multithreaded project, which I need to use this blueprint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass i as an argument in lambda funcion

```
fun_list = [lambda x=i: foo(x) for i in range(5)]
```